# Override default remove()/DELETE in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Rather than deleting a record, our client would like to mark a record as deleted. We are using JPA2/Hibernate. I'd like to do something like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE")
@ActionOverride(action="delete", with="activeFlag = false")
public class Table {
    @Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG")
    boolean activeFlag;

    // ...

}
```

I have done this in the past but I can't seem to find the right syntax and annotation.

Comment: You could do it with a DeleteEventListener, as described [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404964/hibernate-overwrite-sql-delete-with-inheritace/10549817#10549817

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud), the annotation you are looking for is `@SQLDelete`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET ACTIVE_FLAG = false WHERE id = ?")
public class Table {
  @Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG")
  boolean activeFlag;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i am using same `@SQLDelete` but this work when it already inserted but in my case i want to update flag within one thread or (same `@Transactional`)

Answer (score 1):

The annotation seems to be `org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete`:

> SqlDelete Annotation for overwriting Hibernate default DELETE method

You set your custom update SQL in the `sql` attribute.

Comment: i am using same `@SQLDelete` but this work when it already inserted but in my case i want to update flag within one thread or (same `@Transactional`)